# Flushing a Promise queue?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, axios, es6-promise

While writing tests using Jest, an asynchronous mocked Axios request was causing a `setState()` call after a component was mounted. This resulted in console output during the test run.

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const mockAxios = new MockAdapter(axios);

  mockAxios.onGet(logsURL).reply(200, [...axios_logs_simple]);

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Logs />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

And in the `<Logs>` component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(apiURL).then(response => {
    this.setState({data: response.data});
  });
}
```

I found a [blog post](https://bluz71.github.io/2018/01/02/mock-axios-in-react-jest_enzyme-tests.html) showing a solution, but I don't understand how it does anything useful:

```
it('renders without crashing', async () => { //<-- async added here
  const mockAxios = new MockAdapter(axios);

  mockAxios.onGet(logsURL).reply(200, [...axios_logs_simple]);

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Logs />, div);
  await flushPromises(); //<-- and this line here.
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});

const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
```

As I understand it, it creates a new promise that resolves immediately. How can that guarantee other asynchronous code will resolve?

Now, it solved the issue. There are no more console messages during the test run. The test still passes (it's not a very good one). But this just seems like I just landed on the other side of a race condition, rather than preventing the race condition in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will start with the reason why do you need this solution.

The reason is that you don't have the **reference** to the **async task** and you need your test assertion to run **after** the async task.
If you had it, you can just `await` on it, this will assure that your test assertion will run **after** the async task. (in your case it is `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode`)

In your example the async task is inside `componentDidMount` which react calls, so you don't have the reference to the async task.

Usually a simple implementation of `flushPromises` will be:

```js
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
```

This implementation is based on the fact that async operations in javascript are based on **task queue** (javascript has several types of queues for async tasks).
Specifically, promises are queued in a micro-task queue. Each time an async operation (such as http request) finishes the async task dequeues and executes.

[`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.dev/understanding-setimmediate) is a method that gets a callback and stores it on the `Immediates Queue` and will be called in the next iteration of the event loop.
This `Immediates Queue` is checked **after** the Micro-task queue (which holds the promises).

Let's analyze the code, we are creating a new promise which is enqueued at the **end** of the `Micro-task queue`, it's `resolve` will be called on the next iteration of the event loop, that means it will be resolved after all the promises that are already enqueued.

Hope this explanation helps.

**Pay attention** that if inside of the async task you will enqueue a new promise, it will enter the queue at the end, that means that the promise that `flushPromises` return will not run after it.

Few posts / videos for more info:

1. https://blog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: It's worth noting that `setImmediate` was removed from `jsdom` in Jest 27 github.com/facebook/jest/pull/11222, so this will not work any longer in Jest tests. Instead you can use `setTimeout`. So the example becomes:

`const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));`

Comment: How about using `await Promise.resolve();` instead of resolving promise in setTimeout?

Comment: timeout & promises are using separate micro-queues, therefore, adding a resolved promise to the queue won't do the thing...